# Chef: use attributes created dynamically

Tags: attributes, chef-infra, chef-recipe

I have 2 recipes that belongs to the same cookbook.
The first recipe uncompress the `apache-tomcat-xxx.tar.gz` file in `/opt/tomcat/apache-tomcat-xxx`

In that first recipe I do

```
tomcat_folder = ls /opt/tomcat
node.default['tomcat']['home'] = "/opt/tomcat/#{tomcat_folder}"
```

so this attribute is created during execution of that recipe.

My second recipe needs to use that attribute value in resource like:

```
template node.default['tomcat']['home'] ...
directory node.default['tomcat']['home'] ...
```

and

```
ruby_block 
block do
        node.default['tomcat']['home']  ....
```

But I receive errors due to that attribute doesn't exist when it executes.
In some other resources I could make it work using `lazy{…}` blocks, but in those resources I don't know how to make them work.

So my question is, how shall I do to set that attribute from recipe 1 so it is able to be used from recipe 2 when they are executed?

Answer (score 1):

Here you also can use *lazy*, but with some workaround.

```rb
template 'tomcat_home' do
  path lazy { node['tomcat']['home'] }
end

directory 'tomcat_home' do
  path lazy { node['tomcat']['home'] }
end
```

*path* for directory and template is a *name attribute*, which means, if it is not set inside the block it is taken from the name of the resource. This is how you did it before. But if you need lazy evaluation, you can set any string as the name of the resource. Just make sure, you **don't create same resources with same names, but different bodies, as they will overwrite each other.**

Another thing you shouldn't to read an attribute from particular [precedence level](http://docs.opscode.com/essentials_node_object.html#attributes) (default, normal, override). Just `node['tomcat']['home']` is the way to go.